# Weird php form issue

Tags: php, forms, post

I am having a simple but weird issue about post and form elements.

I have a form

```
<form id='form' name='form' method='post' action='test.php'>


      <?php
          foreach ($tests as $test){
              echo $test['ID']."<br>"; //output 1  2  3  4  5   6
              echo $_POST['testSelect'].'<br>';  //output 3 3 3 3 3 3

              if($test['ID'] == $_POST['testSelect']){  //which 3 mataches 3
                  echo 'match';
              }
          }
      ?>



    <select name='testSelect'>
      <?php
          foreach ($tests as $test){
              echo '<option value="'.$test['ID'].'">'.$test['Name'].'</option>';
          }
      ?>
    </select>
     <input type='submit' value='Go'></input>
```

I want to match `$_POST` and my variable and output "`match`" when it matches.

However, I don't see '`Match`' shows in my output. It doesn't make sense at all!

Can Anyone help? Thanks a lot

Comment: http://codepad.org/prSBWILG  your code works but I think you are not considering that either $tests or $_POST value is not the same "type" of variable (such as a int or text)

Comment: please show us how you create $test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just try like

```
if((int)trim($test['ID']) == (int)trim($_POST['testSelect'])){  
  echo 'Matched';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're actually performing a POST request? Turning on error_reporting might help too.

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this has to do with the Post param being a String and the Test param probably being an Integer.
Put parseInt() around the Post variable